# powershell script: Find and replace, and insert lines in a file

Tags: powershell

**Background**

I'm trying to write a small utility that searches through a file to find all instances of lines that look like this:

```
 [SecuredEndpoint(widgets.UpdateWidget)]
```

And make it look like this:

```
 //[SecuredEndpoint(widgets.UpdateWidget)]
 [AllowAnonymous]
```

So far, I have the following script - haven't written it back to the file yet.. just doing everything in memory first.

```
#Find and comment out all [SecuredEndpoint] attributes
(Get-Content -path .\TestController.cs -Raw) -replace '\[SecuredEndpoint','//\[SecuredEnpoint' | Foreach-Object {
        $_ # send the current line to output
        if ($_ -match "//[SecuredEndpoint") 
        {
            #Add Lines after the selected pattern 
            "[AllowAnonymous]"
        }
    }
```

It correctly comments out all the various the SecuredEndpoint lines, but it doesn't insert a new line afterwards.  So the results look like this:

```
    [Route("widgets/")]
    [HttpGet]
    //[SecuredEnpoint(mywidget.GetAll)]
    public List<Widgets> GetWidgets()
    {
    }

    [Route("widgets/)]
    [HttpPost]
    //[SecuredEnpoint(mywidget.Create)]
    public List<Widgets> GetWidgets()
    {
    }
```

I don't get any errors.

**Questions**

What am i missing in the logic to make it insert the new line?
Once that's fixed, I'm assuming I can do something like this to actually save the contents back to the file:

```
(Get-Content -path .\TestController.cs -Raw) -replace '\[SecuredEndpoint','//[SecuredEnpoint' | Foreach-Object {
        $_ # send the current line to output
        if ($_ -match "//\[SecuredEndpoint") 
        {
            #Add Lines after the selected pattern 
            "[AllowAnonymous]"
        }
    } Set-Content .\TestController.cs
```

Please and thanks!

Comment: I'm surprised you don't receive a parsing error - `"//[SecuredEndpoint"` is not a valid regex pattern, it needs to be `"//\[SecuredEnpoint"`

Comment: You could use a literal replacement method ``.Replace('[SecuredEndpoint(widgets.UpdateWidget)]', "//[SecuredEndpoint(widgets.UpdateWidget)]`n[AllowAnonymous]")`` and read the file as single multiline string with `-Raw`

Comment: @SantiagoSquarzon would you mind posting an answer with the sample code?  This way I can make sure I'm following your suggestion properly and accept your answer?  Please and thanks!

Comment: Also in case it wasn't clear, the text after each instance of '[SecuredEndpoint(' can be different so the replace method needs to look for the pattern [SecuredEndpoint*'.    Updating question to be clearer

Comment: The literal replacement method won't work in that case. Doesn't allow wildcards or regex.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The following regex replacement might do the trick:

```
(Get-Content .\TestController.cs -Raw) -replace '\[SecuredEnpoint\(.+?\)]', "// `$0`n[AllowAnonymous]"
```

See https://regex101.com/r/WZDaEx/2 for regex details.

If you want to match `SecuredEnpoint` using case sensitive comparison use `-creplace` instead.

If there could be already commented `[SecuredEnpoint(...)]` lines and you want to avoid adding a new layer of comments you could use the following:

```
(Get-Content .\TestController.cs -Raw) -replace '(?<!//\s*)\[SecuredEnpoint\(.+?\)]', "// `$0`n[AllowAnonymous]"
```

See https://regex101.com/r/6gPgws/1 for regex details.

Comment: ;-}   HA... @Santiago Squarzon, beat me to it. I just posted a similar one, with a minor change, but deleted it when I saw yours.   ;-}   Well, that and you led with the initial prudent answer, that my post was adjusting a bit, to what you just showed in your second response.

Comment: @postanote mind as well undelete it if you have it already ;)

Comment: ;-}  well.... ok. done.

Comment: @postanote I upvoted your answer to thank you!  thanks to you both!

Answer (score 2):

A quick refactoring of '@Santiago Squarzon' helpful answer. Try it this way.

Well, in case there are multiple files that may require updating as well, with other mixed string content.

```
'   
    [Route("widgets/")]
    [HttpGet]
    //[SecuredEnpoint(mywidget.GetAll)]
    public List<Widgets> GetWidgets()
    {
    }

    [Route("widgets/)]
    [HttpPost]
    //[SecuredEnpoint(mywidget.Create)]
    public List<Widgets> GetWidgets()
    {
    }
' | 
Out-File -FilePath 'D:\Temp\TestController.cs' -Force

'   
    [Route("widgets/")]
    [HttpGet]
    //[SecuredRemoteEnpoint(mywidget.GetAll)]
    public List<Widgets> GetWidgets()
    {
    }

    [Route("widgets/)]
    [HttpPost]
    //[SecuredLocalEnpoint(mywidget.Create)]
    public List<Widgets> GetWidgets()
    {
    }
' | 
Out-File -FilePath 'D:\Temp\TestController1.cs' -Force

Clear-Host
(Get-ChildItem -Path 'D:\Temp' -Filter '*TestController*.cs').
ForEach(
    {
        "********* Updating $(($PSItem).Name) content *********"

        Get-Content -Path $PSItem.Fullname 

        (Get-Content $PSItem.Fullname -Raw) -replace '\[Secured.*\]', "`$0`n`t[AllowAnonymous]" | 
        Set-Content -Path $PSItem.Fullname

        Get-Content -Path $PSItem.Fullname 
    }
)

# Results
<#
********* Updating TestController.cs content *********
   
    [Route("widgets/")]
    [HttpGet]
    //[SecuredEnpoint(mywidget.GetAll)]
    public List<Widgets> GetWidgets()
    {
    }

    [Route("widgets/)]
    [HttpPost]
    //[SecuredEnpoint(mywidget.Create)]
    public List<Widgets> GetWidgets()
    {
    }

   
    [Route("widgets/")]
    [HttpGet]
    //[SecuredEnpoint(mywidget.GetAll)]
    [AllowAnonymous]
    public List<Widgets> GetWidgets()
    {
    }

    [Route("widgets/)]
    [HttpPost]
    //[SecuredEnpoint(mywidget.Create)]
    [AllowAnonymous]
    public List<Widgets> GetWidgets()
    {
    }


********* Updating TestController1.cs content *********
   
    [Route("widgets/")]
    [HttpGet]
    //[SecuredRemoteEnpoint(mywidget.GetAll)]
    public List<Widgets> GetWidgets()
    {
    }

    [Route("widgets/)]
    [HttpPost]
    //[SecuredLocalEnpoint(mywidget.Create)]
    public List<Widgets> GetWidgets()
    {
    }

   
    [Route("widgets/")]
    [HttpGet]
    //[SecuredRemoteEnpoint(mywidget.GetAll)]
    [AllowAnonymous]
    public List<Widgets> GetWidgets()
    {
    }

    [Route("widgets/)]
    [HttpPost]
    //[SecuredLocalEnpoint(mywidget.Create)]
    [AllowAnonymous]
    public List<Widgets> GetWidgets()
    {
    }
#>
```